# Navbar collapse não funciona!

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Segue o código para análise:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Idea Agência Digital</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Java <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que realmente está tentando fazer? Um submenu nesse dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na própria documentação do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) mostra que a `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">`
deve vir antes do seu `<div class="container">` .

Fazendo essa alteração o navbar collapse irá funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com esse problema. Não funcionava o dropdown e nem menu collapse quando reduzia a página para versão mobile. Resolvi assim...

1. instale o jquery `npm install jquery --save`
2. no arquivo `angular.json` verifique se em scripts está o caminho para o jquery e bootstrap. Procure por dois locais de `scripts` e adicione nos dois.

   `"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ]`
3. Logo abaixo, vai encontrar outro `scripts` e adicione também.
   `"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
   ]`
4. Vá ao `app.module.ts` e import o jquery

   `import * as $ from 'jquery';`
5. Reinicie o servidor na linha de comando e verifique se resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei recriar um exemplo online no [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) do código acima da tua pergunta, mas não entendi muito bem qual é o teu objectivo ou o que estás a tentar criar, mas para criar uma lista dropdown com o Bootstrap, basta utilizares:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Java
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Exemplo no jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/qqmm9kn6/**

Comment: Acho que ele está tentando criar um submenu desse dropdown

Answer (score -1):

Bem o código está direito... Não deves é estar a importar o bootstrap e o jquery.
Chegas-te a fazer download desses ficheiros, e colocar na pasta do trabalho?

Fiz isto com o teu código e funcinou.

https://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/295/

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">iOS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SVN</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Java <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">jmeter</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EJB</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Jasper Report</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58308)

Comment: @rray Hey brother write in Portuguese please auahhahaha

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues é mensagem automatica da fila, ja devem ter corrigido isso.